# Backtracking Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, knapsack-problem

**So I have to solve a typical knapsack recursion problem and having some issues. I have a boat I must fill with items and mustn't exceed the boats weight and at the same time maximize the value of items put on the boat.
Here is my Item struct**

```
struct Item{
      Item(){ value = 0; weight = 0; count = 0;};
      int value;
      int weight;
      int count;
     };
```

**Here is my boat class**

```
 class Boat{
    public:
     Boat(){
      current_weight = 0;
      total_value = 0;
    };
       Item item_list[];
       int max_weight;
       int item_count;
       int current_weight;
       int total_value;
       bool placeable(Item item){
        Item min = item_list[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < item_count; i++){
         if(item_list[i].weight < min.weight) min = item_list[i];
    }
       if(current_weight += min.weight > max_weight) return false;
       else{return true;}
    };
       void print(){
       for(int i = 0; i < item_count; i++)cout << item_list[i].count << " Item " << i+1 << endl;
       cout << "Total Weight: " << current_weight << endl;
       cout << "Total Value: "  << total_value << endl;
      };
       void add(Item &item){
         current_weight+=item.weight;
         total_value+=item.value;
         item.count++;
         cout << current_weight <<" " << total_value << endl;
      };
       void remove(Item &item){
         current_weight-=item.weight;
         total_value-=item.value;
         item.count--;
         cout << current_weight <<" " << total_value << endl;
      };
      bool solved(){
       if(current_weight == max_weight)return true;
       else{return false;}
      };
    };
```

**And here is my solve_from function where the backtracking takes place**

```
bool solve_from(Boat &boat){
   if(boat.solved()){
     boat.print();
     return true;
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < boat.item_count; i++){
          if(boat.placeable(boat.item_list[i])){
           boat.add(boat.item_list[i]);
           bool solved = solve_from(boat);
           boat.remove(boat.item_list[i]);
           if(solved) return true;
    }
   }
     return false;
}
}
```

**And my main**

```
 int main(){
      Boat boat;
      int size;
      cout << "Enter weight capacity: " << endl;
      cin >> boat.max_weight;
      cout << "How many valuable items: " << endl;
      cin >> size;
      boat.item_count = size;
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
         Item item;
         cout << "Enter weight of item " << i+1<< ": " << endl;
         cin  >> item.weight;
         cout << "Enter value of item " << i+1 << ": " << endl;
         cin  >> item.value;
         boat.item_list[i] = item;
        }
        solve_from(boat);
    }
```

We are given test inputs of

- The weight capacity of the boat = 17  The number of valuable item
  types = 3  Item type 1: weight = 3, value = 7  Item type 2: weight =
  6, value = 13  Item type 3: weight= 7, value = 15

With the output being 1 Item 1 and 2 Item 2.

**However I keep getting either stuck in the recursion loop resulting in seg fault or just random numbers. I am just looking for some help to point me in the right direction, I would sure appreciate it thanks!**

Comment: `Item item_list[];` this is what?

Comment: @manni66 A list of possible choices to fill the boat with. At least that is how I thought I implemented it?

Comment: It should not compile. Don't know how you managed to run the program. Use std::vector.

Comment: @manni66 Probably compiler extension combined with undefined behaviour.

Comment: "knapsacking" would be trying to minimize the total number of boats, not to maximize the value load of one.

Comment: @WillNess I do believe you are incorrect sir. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @Drogo thanks, I'll recheck my understanding of this. I always thought it that way -- that it's much better to have three boats, say, at 90% capacity each, than to have one at 99% and be stuck with a small leftover necessitating the fourth boat, as a result.